# Python Parsing Trace File

Tags: python, json, readfile

I have a trace file downloaded from **chrome://bookmarks** and it looks like this

```
{"args":{"name":"Chrome_ChildIOThread"},"cat":"__metadata","name":"thread_name","ph":"M","pid":24050,"tid":13059,"ts":0},
{"args":{"name":"Compositor"},"cat":"__metadata","name":"thread_name","ph":"M","pid":24050,"tid":42243,"ts":0},
{"args":{"name":"CompositorTileWorker1"},"cat":"__metadata","name":"thread_name","ph":"M","pid":24050,"tid":23555,"ts":0},
{"args":{"name":"CompositorTileWorker2"},"cat":"__metadata","name":"thread_name","ph":"M","pid":24050,"tid":40963,"ts":0},
{"args":{"name":"ThreadPoolForegroundWorker"},"cat":"__metadata","name":"thread_name","ph":"M","pid":24050,"tid":12035,"ts":0},
{"args":{"name":"Chrome_ChildIOThread"},"cat":"__metadata","name":"thread_name","ph":"M","pid":17240,"tid":13315,"ts":0},
{"args":{"name":"Chrome_ChildIOThread"},"cat":"__metadata","name":"thread_name","ph":"M","pid":17247,"tid":13059,"ts":0},
{"args":{"name":"Chrome_ChildIOThread"},"cat":"__metadata","name":"thread_name","ph":"M","pid":17244,"tid":18435,"ts":0},
```

I would like to read this file and load into a dictionary to get the traces that name is equal to **Chrome_ChildIOThread** and so on. How can I do that?

Comment: To me, it looks like a bunch of JSON objects, one per line.

Comment: Yep, it's [JSON Lines format](https://jsonlines.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that the data you've shown as input is in a file called bookmarks.txt then this should suffice:

```
D = {'data': []}

with open('bookmarks.txt') as bm:
    for line in bm:
        try:
            i = line.rindex('}') + 1
            j = eval(line[:i])
            if j['args']['name'] == 'Chrome_ChildIOThread':
                D['data'].append(j)
        except (ValueError, KeyError):
            pass
print(D)
```